# Powershell - Sort files into directory based on file name

Tags: powershell, sorting, directory

I'm trying to sort my files into unique dictionaries based on the file name and delimiters.

File names follow this structure:
**LocationName-DP-Category-S-L**

Where...
**-** is the delimiter

- **Location name** is a variable length, never has spaces
- **DP** is the two-letter department code
- **Category** is a variable length, never has spaces
- **S** is a single-letter size code
- **L** is length

Everything after category is irrelevant, as there is often some extra garble at the end of the filename to ignore.

I'd like to have a folder structure created and sorted for every found variation of just the LocationName-DP-Category portion of the filepath that looks something like this:

- Parent Folder: LocationName
- SubFolder: DP
- SubSubFolder: Category

Trying to keep it less rigid as this runs often on various batches of files. Here's what I have:

```
##GET USER INPUT FROM DIALOG
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$null = $browser.ShowDialog()
$path = $browser.SelectedPath + "\"

##SORT ALL FILES
Get-ChildItem -Path $path *-*-*-*-*.* |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '(?<store>\w+)\-+(?<dept>\w+)\-+(?<category>\w+)*.*'|
    Group-Object {$Matches["store"]+'-'+$Matches["dept"]+'-'+$Matches["Category"]}|
      ForEach-Object{mkdir $_.Name;$_.Group|Move-Item -Dest $_.Name}
```

Would really appreciate the help, been scratching my head on and off for a couple months.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

...initially I also thought about group-object but I think that is not necessary, this is simpler:

```
#Get Source Files
$files = get-childitem -Path [path]
#Set target root path
$targetPathRoot = "C:\tmp\"
#Loop through array of files
foreach ($file in $files){
    #Split the filename 
    $split = $file.name -split "-"
    #Build the target path
    $newFullPath = $targetPathRoot + $split[0] + '\' + $split[1] + '\' + $split[2]
    #If path exists move item, otherwise create path and move item
    If (Test-Path $newFullPath){
        $null = move-item -Path $file.psPath -Destination $newFullPath
    }
    Else {
        $null = new-item -ItemType Directory -Path $newFullPath -Force
        $null = move-item -Path $file.psPath -Destination $newFullPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I played around with split for a while but could never get it quite right - I'm still pretty new to powershell. Really appreciate you breaking it down and showing the code. Will give this a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of the parts 'LocationName', 'DP' or 'Category' contain a hyphen, you could create the new path for the file like this:

```
# 'LocationName-DP-Category-S-L-blah.ext' --> LocationName\DP\Category
$_.BaseName -replace '^(\w+-\w{2}-\w+).*', '$1' -replace '-', '\'
```

Your code can then become

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$null = $browser.ShowDialog()
$path = $browser.SelectedPath
$browser.Dispose()  # remove from memory when done

# the root path for the (new) subfolders and files
$destination = 'X:\SomeWhere'
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($path)) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*-*-*-*-*.*' -File | ForEach-Object {
        $subPath   = $_.BaseName -replace '^(\w+-\w{2}-\w+).*', '$1' -replace '-', '\'
        $targetDir = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $subPath
        # create the new path if it does not already exist
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetDir -ItemType Directory -Force
        # move the file
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $targetDir
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Folder dialog cancelled"
}
```

Note: On the **File System**, the `New-Item -Path $targetDir -ItemType Directory -Force` will either create the new folder, OR return a reference to an existing folder. The `-Force` switch in this case allows you not to have to use `Test-Path` in this case.
Mind you, you should NOT use that technique when dealing with other systems like on registry keys for instance